# Bootstrap: Container is smaller than its columns, they cause an overflow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, containers

I have an attached background image on the container, but it only goes with like half the columns and then the columns overflow and the bg image stops.
i tried min-height
the 2 columns are in a container and the columns contain multiple rows
i don't understand why on earth the container is not growing with the columns

HTML:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"> </head>

<body>
  <div class="bg-primary text-center d-flex align-items-center h-50" style="background-image: url(&quot;projektberge.png&quot;);">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h1 class="display-1 text-white">COVER</h1>
          <p class="lead text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Button</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar2SupportedContent" aria-controls="navbar2SupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-center justify-content-center" id="navbar2SupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="attached" style="background-image: url(&quot;FB-1_Christopher Gusenbauer_PanoramaBahnhof.jpg&quot;);">
    <div class="h-100">
      <div class="container-fluid w-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="row" style="height:100%">
              <div class="col-md-2 h-100 bg-primary" style="height:100%">
                <h1 class="">Summary</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-10 h-100">
                <div class="row ">
                  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid w-100">
                    <div class="container">
                      <h1 class="display-3">Jumbotron</h1>
                      <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-primary">
                    <div class="col-md-6 bg-secondary">
                      <img class="img-fluid d-block py-3" src="https://pingendo.com/assets/photos/wireframe/photo-1.jpg"> </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 py-3">
                      <h1 class="">Heading</h1>
                      <p class="">Paragraph</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 bg-primary">
                      <div class="container">
                        <header class="page-header">
                          <h1>Dark Responsive Timeline with Bootstrap</h1>
                        </header>
                        <ul class="timeline">
                          <li>
                            <div class="tldate">Apr 2014</div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>Surprising Headline Right Here</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 3 hours ago</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>Lorem Ipsum and such.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>Breaking into Spring!</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 4/07/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>Hope the weather gets a bit nicer...</p>
                                <p>Y'know, with more sunlight.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="tldate">Mar 2014</div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>New Apple Device Release Date</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 3/22/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>In memory of Steve Jobs.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>No icon here</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 3/16/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>Here you'll find some beautiful photography for your viewing pleasure, courtesy of
                                  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/">lorempixel</a>.</p>
                                <p>
                                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/300/nightlife/" alt="lorem pixel"> </p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>Some Important Date!</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 3/03/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>Write up a quick summary of the event.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="timeline-panel noarrow">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>Secondary Timeline Box</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 3/01/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>This might be a follow-up post with related info. Maybe we include some extra links, tweets, user comments, photos, etc.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="tldate">Feb 2014</div>
                          </li>
                          <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>The Winter Months</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 02/23/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>Gee time really flies when you're having fun.</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                            <div class="tl-circ"></div>
                            <div class="timeline-panel">
                              <div class="tl-heading">
                                <h4>Yeah we're pretty much done here</h4>
                                <p><small class="text-muted"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 02/11/2014</small></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tl-body">
                                <p>Wasn't this fun though?</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row"> </div>
                  <div class="row"> </div>
                  <div class="row"> </div>
                  <div class="row"> </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://pingendo.com/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.min.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Boostrap 4 alpha 6.

It's fixed in Boostrap 4 beta 1 that it's under development.
I noticed you are using Pingendo, you can use the Bootstrap 4 beta 1 version changing the import at the end of your sass file in

```
@import 'bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't included bootstrap references inside your head tag

Here are the links - [Bootstrap Js Link](https://%3Cscript%20src=%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js%22%20integrity=%22sha512-vyRAVI0IEm6LI/fVSv/Wq/d0KUfrg3hJq2Qz5FlfER69sf3ZHlOrsLriNm49FxnpUGmhx+TaJKwJ+ByTLKT+Yg==%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%20referrerpolicy=%22no-referrer%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

[Bootstrap CSS Link](https://%3Clink%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20href=%22https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20integrity=%22sha512-siwe/oXMhSjGCwLn+scraPOWrJxHlUgMBMZXdPe2Tnk3I0x3ESCoLz7WZ5NTH6SZrywMY+PB1cjyqJ5jAluCOg==%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%20referrerpolicy=%22no-referrer%22%20/%3E)

Add them like this.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-siwe/oXMhSjGCwLn+scraPOWrJxHlUgMBMZXdPe2Tnk3I0x3ESCoLz7WZ5NTH6SZrywMY+PB1cjyqJ5jAluCOg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-vyRAVI0IEm6LI/fVSv/Wq/d0KUfrg3hJq2Qz5FlfER69sf3ZHlOrsLriNm49FxnpUGmhx+TaJKwJ+ByTLKT+Yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Javascript reads from bottom to top, so inserting them in the <head> tag will cause slower load times, style links in header, javascript links bottom of body.

Comment: Whatever works for you.